# Installing mingw-w64-g++ 4.8 on Ubuntu Precise

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, travis-ci, mingw-w64, g++4.8

Is there any way to install mingw-w64-g++ 4.8 on Ubuntu Precise (12.04) in order to cross compile to Windows through a ppa?
It's needed for C++11 support on TravisCI

Answer (score 0):

If you just need C++11 you can use the following commands as a sample to install a newer version of GCC/G++

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gcc-5 g++-5
sudo update-alternatives 
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all gcc
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all g++
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 20
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5 20
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
sudo update-alternatives --config g++
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. But I would like mingw-w64. On another note, I could use appveyor